# La pathologie nommée dépression peut aller d’une forme atténuée de vague à l’âme à une maladie qui peut compromettre le pronostic vital

Tags: grammaire

La pathologie nommée dépression peut aller d’une forme atténuée de vague à l’âme à une maladie qui peut compromettre le pronostic vital.

who can help me with the understanding of

1. 'une forme atténuée de vague à l’âme à une maladie'
2. 'pronostic vital'

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The expression used is *peut aller de xxx à yyy*, i.e. "might range from xxx to yyy".

Here *xxx* is *une forme atténuée de vague à l’âme* (mild blues) and *yyy* is *une maladie qui peut compromettre le pronostic vital*.

*Pronostic vital* means that life is at risk so *yyy* is "a potentially lethal disease".

Comment: @montéedelait Thanks for the correction. Maybe did the proximity with "lethal" somewhat turn that *disease* into a *decease* ;-)